# Unable to change more than one phong material for an object on key press

Tags: javascript, three.js

Thanks to Stack overflow community for helping ammature coders like me, here i'm trying to switch phong materials for a .obj loaded model on keypress, However for some reason it is only taking the first element in the material array on key press. i have made sure the looping is proper.

here is the [DEMO](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andyram08/neavik/master/issue.html), Please let me know if there is anyway to resolve this

[CODE](https://github.com/andyram08/neavik/blob/master/issue.html)

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="three.js"></script>

    <script src="DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="orbitcontrols.js"></script>
    <script>
        // three.js info box follows shape
        var renderer, scene, camera;
        current = 0;
        var Black = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0x000000,
            combine: THREE.MixOperation,
            specular: 0xfafafa, //bbaa99,
            shininess: 70,
            emissive: 0x000000,
            reflectivity: 0.7
        })
        var White = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0xf6daa5,
            //  specular: 0x000000,
            shininess: 0,
            //  bumpMap: mapHeight,
            bumpScale: 12,
            emissive: null,
            emissiveIntensity: null,
            //  envMap: textureCube,
            //  combine: THREE.MixOperation,
            reflectivity: 0.1
        });
        var cleanWhite = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0xffffef,
            specular: 0x000000,
            combine: THREE.AddOperation,
            reflectivity: 0
        })
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            // info
            var info = document.createElement('div');
            info.style.position = 'absolute';
            info.style.top = '30px';
            info.style.width = '100%';
            info.style.textAlign = 'center';
            info.style.color = '#fff';
            info.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            info.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
            info.style.zIndex = '1';
            info.style.fontFamily = 'Monospace';
            info.innerHTML = "three.js - Material change: PRESS C to change colors";
            document.body.appendChild(info);
            // document.body.addEventListener('keyup', onMouseUp);
            // renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            // scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // ambient light
            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
            scene.add(ambient);
            // directional light
            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
            directionalLight.position.set(-1, -0.5, 1);
            scene.add(directionalLight);
            //  var bookup = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "js/ice.jpg" );
            var cleanBookup = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                //  map:bookup,
                //color:16777200,
                specular: 0x000000,
                combine: THREE.AddOperation,
                reflectivity: 0.4
            })
            var onError = function(xhr) {};
            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
            var mtl1Loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            var lambert = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
            mtl1Loader.setBaseUrl('');
            mtl1Loader.setPath('');
            mtl1Loader.load('Book_Cover.mtl', function(materials) {
                materials.preload();
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.setPath('');
                objLoader.load('Book_Cover.obj', function(object2) {
                    object2.castShadow = true;
                    object2.receiveShadow = true;
                    object2.updateMatrix();
                    object2.position.set(300, 950, 800);
                    object2.scale.x = object2.scale.y = 0.8;
                    object2.frustumCulled = true;
                    object2.traverse(function(child) {
                        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                            if (child.material.name == "Book_Cover") {
                                //   child.material.visible=false;
                                //  child.material.color = new THREE.Color(16775930);
                                //  child.material=cleanBookup;  // when i include this the effect onkey press wont change at all
                                child.castShadow = true;
                                child.receiveShadow = true;
                                ////////////IMPORTANT PART FROM HERE WHICH IS AN ISSUE//////                   
                                var index = 0;
                                var onKeyDown = function(event) {
                                    if (event.keyCode == 67) { // when 'c' is pressed
                                        colors = [White, Black, cleanWhite];
                                        //  for (var i=0;i<colors.length;i++) {
                                        object2.traverse(function(child) {
                                            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                                                if (child.material.name == "Book_Cover") {
                                                    if (index == colors.length) index = 0;
                                                    child.material = colors[index++];
                                                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                                                    child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                                                    child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    //  object.material.color.setHex(0xff0000); // there is also setHSV and setRGB
                                    //  }
                                };
                                document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyDown, true);
                            }
                        }
                        scene.add(object2);
                    });
                });
            })
            //  object2.updateMatrix();
            // camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
            camera.position.set(20, -10, 100);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            // camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
            var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75);
            light.position.set(0.5, 1, 0.75);
            scene.add(light);
            // controls
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
            controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            controls.update();
        }
        // render
        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        // animate
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any one faced a similar problem before ?